# Can you pin a particular version of a chroot?

Tags: debootstrap

The question may quite make sense due to my chroot newbiness, but what I mean to ask is how I can make sure that when I create a new chroot, I download the same set of files each time.  In the git world, I want to clone with a particular commit:

```
sudo debootstrap trusty path/to/my/chroot
```

I want to pin that `SUITE` and creating an overall git repo inside the chroot after the `TARGET` seems like I'm going against the grain.  I'm tracking in what seems to be a redundant way, and a LOT of stuff, and I get errors:

```
root/.bashrc: Permission denied
root/.profile: Permission denied
```

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man8/debootstrap.8.html

Comment: Docker seems like a better fit here, since it's filesystem layers are similar to commits and offers the same basic functionality as a chroot.